# Eclipse Link @CascadeOnDelete not working

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data, eclipselink

I am using `EclipseLink` and  having following config files

orm.xml
[image]

pom.xml

[image]

As this annotation is available from version 2.2 and as my config says version 2.6.3 so it has to work, I applied the annotation as describe [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DeleteCascade) , but it is not working and I am getting exception while deleting my parent entity. However after adding ON DELETE CASCADE at database level I am able to delete. I want to know what I am missing due to which unable to achieve it from annotation.

In my `orm.xml` there is a url that downloads `xsd` (i.e. 2.0) is it something old that causes and dont understand what it is actually and what actual version of eclipse link in use.

Answer (score 0):

@CascadeOnDelete is to tell JPA you have the "ON DELETE CASCADE" option being used in the database so it doesn't issue the delete statements and lets the DB do it. It will instead just clean up the cache references from the cache assuming the delete completes. If you don't have the "ON DELETE CASCADE" database option set, then you shouldn't use @CascadeOnDelete and instead have JPA cascade the delete or manually handle it in the application.

The ORM xsd you refer to is the schema used for validating the ORM. It was created against a version 2 of the JPA specification, and does not say anything or affect the EclipseLink version you decide to use as long as it implements JPA.

Comment: Thnx sir for the reply ..I want to reconfirm two things FIRST if i dont use annotation and simply use "ON DELETE CASCADE" on database what difference it makes? SECOND if i neither use annotation nor DB level than how JPA handle it ,is it by _CascadeType.Remove_